# Passing KeyValuePair with string and array value API Request Model Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, model-view-controller

I'm struggling with the KeyValuePair request model API on how to pass the array value on string parameter. This is what it looks like on API:

```
{
  "answers": ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango"]
}
```

Then, this is my code on Controller:

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("answers", model.Answers.ToList())
 });

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.PostAsync("verification-questions", content).Result;
```

And this is the error I received:

> cannot convert form system.collections.generic.list to string[]

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an `array` instead of `List`.

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>("answers", model.Answers.ToArray())
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm getting also an error